# How to filter country from latitude and longitude?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, geospatial, geo

I have a CSV of 2 Million row. There only two columns Latitude and longitude. I want to filter a country. For example, I want to filter only india's lat and long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: please read the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to find a country from lat longs i.e. Online and Offline. I'll explain both below:

## Online

You need to install a package called [`geopy`](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/)

```
pip install geopy
```

Following code will let you reverse geocode the latitude and longitude using OpenStreetMap geocoding web service

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test_app")  # enter a name for your app
location = geolocator.reverse("27.1751, 78.0421")
print(location.raw['address']['country'])
```

However, it is not reliable.

## Offline

A better option is to use offline geocoding using [`reverse-geocode`](https://pypi.org/project/reverse-geocode/)

```
pip install reverse-geocode
```

Here's the sample code

```
import reverse_geocode
coords = (27.1751, 78.0421), (28.5245, 77.1855)
reverse_geocode.search(coords)
```